# Moving rows (copying) that satisfy some condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have a table that looks something like this

```
Column A1   Column B1     Column C1
A1              6            0%
A1-Sportback    6            33%
A3-New          3            6%
A3-Sportback    0            -
A4-2015         4            35%
Q3              0            -
Q5              5            32%
Q7-2015         0            -
TT-new          6            13%
```

And I want to copy-move all rows that contain a value <20% in column C1 as a separate table. I can't use VBA however, because this is to be imported into google sheets

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a fourth "Marker" column.

```
=if(C2<0.2,1,0)
```

Then filter the sheet to if the fourth column contains 1.
This will give you everything less than 20% (0.2 if stored as number or percentage).
Then copy your rows to a new table.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. However, I need to automate it and like I said, can't use VBA

Comment: you realise you can use a macro for this. the macro doesn't have to be in the output sheet. Your macro book would open the source book, copy the rows that meet the criteria to a new book, and save the new book as csv. Fully uploadable and ready to rock.